# .Net Application Roles Authorization Using Active Directory Groups

Tags: .net-3.5, active-directory, authorization

I am new to both .net and Active Directory (AD) so this may be a simple answer but I have been searching the web and MSDN library for hours and find bits and pieces for what I'm looking to do but am not sure how to pull them all together. I am developing an intranet .net app and want to authenticate and authorize users based on their Windows network username logon against 2 AD groups. I want the application to allow users in ADusergroup1 to see all pages of the app and users in ADusergroup2 to see a restricted number of pages of the app.

From what I have read, it seems the best way to do this is by setting `<authenticationmode="Windows"/>`, using `<rolemanager>` to define roles based on the AD groups, and defining `<authorization>` per location path based on the defined roles. However, I'm still uncertain how to define and use the roles using `<rolemanager>`. Does someone have an example of a web.config file to do this? And once this is defined in the web.config file, does anything else need to be done in the app code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There were many questions about AD and role provider like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726837/user-group-and-role-management-in-net-with-active-directory), try to search first.

Comment: Thanks, I did search a lot (web and MSDN) and actually saw this example. It seemed overly complex for what I was trying to do though and honestly I had trouble following it but I'll look into the code further to see if I can decipher what it's doing and which functions are applicable for what I'm trying to do. Guess I should have pointed out in question that using VB as well.

Comment: Example I gave you is showing one of the best ways to achive that, it's like a reusable block you just fit into your application. If you want to have it less complicated, just override IsUserInRole method check if user is in any of your groups if so return true, as I remeber it's enought to make it work.

Comment: Will definitely try the code block. However, having problems getting past the IIS/ASP.NET authentication right now as I continue to get the Windows login prompt even though IIS set to Windows Authentication with other security disabled and have web.config <authorization> as <allow users = "*"/>. Been troubleshooting issue for over a day now and cannot figure out the problem. Based on posts I've seen, I confirmed URL does not include periods, double checked that IE settings are set to Enable Integrated Windows Authentication, and also added URL to intranet sites, but still getting the pop-up.