# Check Role information C# wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, active-directory

i have string username and string password. i need to authenticate the user and check for role membership against active directory in WCF. what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the answer to this question - you should be able to use this to get what you're looking for:

[User Group and Role Management in .NET with Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726837/user-group-and-role-management-in-net-with-active-directory)