# Combining DirectoryServices.AccountManagement & Role Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, directoryservices, roleprovider, account-management

Is it possible to use a custom role provider, or Windows/SQL for that matter, with System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement? I validate the users this way and it would be nice if I could use a role provider to manage website content. Is this even possible?

Comment: You could probably create your own custom membership based on S.DS.AM, and an accompanying role provider. But why bother? There already *is* an Active Directory membership + role provider - why not just use those?

Comment: I believe that requires setting up groups in AD but we have way to many to try to manage access for, thus I use a custom users table that specifies the role.

Comment: You could use the standard AD membership provider (all your users do have AD accounts, right?), and then create your own database-based role provider (instead of using AD groups as roles)

Comment: Well, I sort of have that now but I don't know how to set up it like the usual role membership (i.e. setting access to an entire folder)... I guess that's the gap that I don't know how to fill.

Comment: Is what you are looking for?
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726837/user-group-and-role-management-in-net-with-active-directory