# Map Active Directory Users to Internal Groups

Tags: c#, .net, database, active-directory, privileges

We have an in-house database that works with Users & Groups, and assigns Rights to certain Groups, and assigns Groups to Users.

We're looking to integrate this with Active Directory and I had a few questions on the subject.

If our software creates the groups "Administrators" and "Employees", how do we go about assigning AD users to these groups? Is this something where the local system administrator who wants to use our software will have to make compatible groups to match up with the groups we've defined in our software?

Basically, I would like some references, or clarification on the process of giving our internal rights to AD Users / Groups. We're using SQLite to provide an embedded, encrypted Database which holds our internal users/groups/rights.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to 'clone' the users that exist in the directory server, you can do it with a batch file or powershell (or C# if you prefer) script that just iterates over the directory groups/users and recreates them in their representation in your application.

If you are trying to authenticate via a directory server, and get the user information from the thread identity or from the other authentication mechanisms in .net land, you'll need to get a bit dirty, especially if the directory server software and versions vary from customer to customer.

Which is your goal?

Comment: It seems people prefer having AD handle the security of log in and authentication (and most likely rightfully so.) So a simple copy of the groups would not suffice. 

I see this thread which sounds similar to my problem, but I am still a bit hazy on the concepts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726837/user-group-and-role-management-in-net-with-active-directory?rq=1

Comment: If you are not familiar with directory service authentication, and the various versions of network authentication using directory services as the store, in windows, then I would recommend you tread carefully.
It is very difficult to rely on a directory server that is outside of your control, so the network environment will change from customer to customer. If they are on domains already, why not just use windows security to handle the authentication. And for authorization you could bake your own scheme.